# Is anybody able to open this jpg with opencv 2.4.3?

Tags: image, opencv, loadimage

i have a problem to open this picture in with OpenCV-2.4.3 functions imread, cvLoadImage and cvLoadImageM. It returns me always an empty Mat or IplImagepointer. Many many other jpg.s are working but not this one, but i can open it with other viewers like gimp or Gwenview.

I am using Qt Creator with OpenSuse 12.2.
Thank you.

PS: Before i can show the image, i need some reputations. Is there another way to load up? I am new.

Comment: This is the image

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwlypszkxcnmgla/Wappen_Erfurt_Gro%C3%9F.jpg

Thank you

Comment: The ways to earn rep are: upvotes on questions and answers (and bounties on answers), and approved suggested edits. +1 from me to get you started. You might want to add a snippet of the code that's failing and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

No, but after I renamed it to "Wappen_Erfurt_Gross.jpg", works OK. The problem is with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure he will come back for that, but since you got it right I up voted it. Nice work.